# Halcon 9.0 generating errors under Windows 10 (but not Windows 8.1)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, squish, halcon

We are currently developing a C++ application (with VS2015) which uses Qt (5.9, for the UI framework) and Halcon 9.0 (for image processing).

Recently we decided to use Squish to facilitate UI tests, and the initial test suites were executed without issues on my system (which runs windows 8.1). Then we tried to add these test suites to our CI environment (similar setup, but running Windows 10).

This is were we encountered the aforementioned issue: The application runs fine when launched "normally", but if it is launched via Squish (or Squish's "startaut" tool) Halcon produces the following errors:

[image: Halcon error 2985]
 followed by
[image: Halcon error 2850].

The halcon manual is notoriously sparse regarding the cause of these errors (and Halcon support speed seems glacial at the moment - 2 weeks and no response to our query yet) - so, even if this a longshot: Has anyone else encountered such (or similar) issues (Halcon 9.0 on Windows 10) and if so, have you figured out a solution?

Comment: Can you run the test via the Squish IDE on the other machine, using the same logon session and user as the CI environment? If not, perhaps there is some relevant information in the "Runner/Server Log" view? Is the working directory in the test suite settings set to a proper value on that other machine?

Comment: The working directory is set correctly. I probably won't be able to run Squish and the IDE on the same logon session since the CI PC has its own user/login. Looking at the Runner/Server Log unfortunately provided no insights - no errors (or unusual stuff) were reported there.

Comment: I recommend contacting the vendor, but for that you need to have the above things checked anyway to start the problem analysis, rule out what contributes, what does not, etc.

Comment: Try contacting your license reseller instead of MvTec. I don't have quotable information, but lets say the advice doesn't come from nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Our reseller is too rather swamped with support requests, but they promised they would see what they can get out of MVTek. (According to them Halcon 9.0 does not officially support Windows 8 and up, so MVTek's response might just be "buy the new version and see if it works then" *sigh*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received word that Halcon 9.x does not officially support Windows 8 and above.
However (fortunately) issue seems resolved in Halcon 9.0.4, which we just received from our license reseller (MVTek does provide downloads of older versions of Halcon, but you need to request download links from them).

So, in a way, the issue is resolved: update to version 9.0.4 of Halcon.